# In V8, would a non-assigned `Escape`d handle be a target of garbage collection immediately?

Tags: v8

There're two functions: one called `make_a_handle` `Escape`s a handle with `EscapableHandleScope`, and another one called `do_something` has its own `HandleScope`. Assuming the `do_something` function calls the `make_a_handle`, and never assigns nor uses the `Escape`d handle; would the `Escape`d handle be a target of garbage collection *immediately*, or *live* until the destruction of the `do_something`'s `HandleScope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter. An `EscapableHandleScope`'s `Escape` function internally uses an "escape slot", which is essentially a handle in the outer `HandleScope`.

For clarity, I'd also like to point out that when a `HandleScope` is destructed, objects referred to by its handles (assuming that was the last reference to them) will not be freed immediately; they only become eligible for garbage collection, which means they will be freed in the next garbage collection cycle.